# Lithium form helper HTML template

Tags: php, helper, lithium, form-helpers

I want to generate a) When writing b) I believe That Is possible with form helpers / templates .

a)

```
<div class="SomeClass">
    <span>
        <i class="some OtherClass "></i>
    </span>
    <input type="text" ... >
</div>
<h4 class="error">Validation Message Goes Here</h4>
```

b )

```
<?= $this->form->field('name',array('label'=>false, 'placeholder'=>'someHolder')); ? >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lithium form class have amazing comments.

You should try something like this:

```php
<?php
echo $this->form->create(null);
echo $this->form->field(
    'name',
    [
        'template' => '<div{:wrap}><span><i class="some OtherClass"></i></span>{:input}</div>',
        'wrap' => ['class' => 'SomeClass'],
    ]
);
echo $this->form->error('name', null, ['template' => '<h4 class="error">{:content}</h4>']);
echo $this->form->end();
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your response. I also wan to to pass some OtherClass when creating the element...

Comment: String replace on the template variable.

Comment: Sorry can you give an example?

Comment: You can't do that replacement with Li3 Form class. You have two choices: extend `Form` class and override `field()` method. Or use that class in you template as a variables: `'template' => '<div{:wrap}><span><i class="some ' . $mySpanClass . '"></i></span>{:input}</div>',`.